# SP.UI.ModalDialog close method returns home.aspx

Tags: modal-dialog

I have 4 webparts on home page. on maximizing any webpart opens a SharePoint modal popup. While closing that modal popup SP.UI.ModalDialog close method returns home.aspx in ajax call. And it takes 20 seconds to return home page. i want to avid this and want to refresh particular webpart only. All web parts are designed using update panel.

Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: How much elements have You got on List ? Meybe o much ? Could You give a sample of code ?